# Use JavaScript SDK in Vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I'm trying to use the [ConvertAPI JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/ConvertAPI/convertapi-js) in a Vue project. First, I used `npm` to install it:

```sh
npm install --save convertapi-js
```

Then, I tried to import and invoke it like so:

```html
<script>
import ConvertApi from 'convertapi-js'
export default {
    created() {
        console.log(ConvertApi.auth({secret: 'secret'})
    }
}
</script>
```

However, when I try to use it I get this error:

> Error in created hook: "TypeError: convertapi_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.auth is not a function"

Do I need to import it in a different way? Here's the structure of the `node_module`:

```
convertapi-js
│   README.md
│   package.json   
│   LICENSE
│
└───lib
│   │   convertapi.d.ts
│   │   convertapi.d.ts.map
│   │   convertapi.js
│   │   convertapi.js.map
│   │   
└───src
    │   convertapi.ts
    │   file-param.ts
    │   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `convertapi-js` [output](https://unpkg.com/convertapi-js@1.0.6/lib/convertapi.js) doesn't have any exports. It simply sets a global named `ConvertApi`, as it's intended to be imported from `<script>` (e.g., before your app's `<script>`).

If you want to use the NPM installed version instead, you can use Webpack's `exports-loader` to export the `ConvertApi` global, so that your Vue code can import it:

1. Install [`exports-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/exports-loader/) with:

   ```
   npm i -D exports-loader
   ```
2. Either [specify the loader inline](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline):

   ```js
   import { ConvertApi } from 'exports-loader?type=commonjs&exports=ConvertApi!convertapi-js'
   ```

   Or [configure Webpack](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration) to automatically use `exports-loader` for `convertapi-js`:

   ```js
   // vue.config.js
   module.exports = {
     configureWebpack: {
       module: {
         rules: [
           {
             test: require.resolve('convertapi-js'),
             loader: 'exports-loader',
             options: {
               type: 'commonjs',
               exports: 'ConvertApi',
             },
           },
         ],
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   Then, use a named import in your Vue code:

   ```js
   import { ConvertApi } from 'convertapi-js'
   ```